# Highcharts contour curves with categories

Tags: highcharts, heatmap, contour, delaunay

I am using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsj5uzdw/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=nsj5uzdw) as a starting point.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
        },

        chart: {
            type: 'contour',
            inverted: true
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts heat map study',
            align: 'left'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day and hour through April 2013',
            align: 'left'
        },

        xAxis: {
            tickPixelInterval: 50,
            min: Date.UTC(2013, 3, 1),
            max: Date.UTC(2013, 3, 30)
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}:00'
            },
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24],
            tickWidth: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: 23
        },

        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, '#3060cf'],
                [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
                [0.9, '#c4463a']
            ],
            min: -5
        },

        series: [{
            borderWidth: 0,
            colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

But instead of putting the date on the Y axis, I want to put some categories there. I name it rules in my example.  In the X axis, I have a range, from 0 to an arbitrary number.

So I want to say, for Rule 1, at point 0, the value is 10; and at point 1, the value is -10; and for Rule 2, at point 0, the value is 15, and at point 1, the value is -7... The values are random/arbitrary.

This is my [attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/qtm3L3kw/1/): http://jsfiddle.net/qtm3L3kw/1/

but nothing is shown.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can i have hardcoded data instead of looping in jsfiddle?